# google map marker is not added to the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on google maps api on web

This is my code

```
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Just the map is shown but the marker is not, **why please?**

I have a second question please. What is the best action the user expect to click (or do) what they want to add a marker on the map?

Thanks

Comment: It works fine here : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/x8dSP/3523/  Do you have any other code to show which might be the issue?

Comment: @KamleshKushwaha it seems yes it is working and i was typing the ID wrong. now I still need the answer for the second question, can u help please?

Comment: I believe click will be the better option here. Although, I may not be the right person to answer this you can still ask this question in http://ux.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @KamleshKushwaha type an answer to accept it please

Comment: Done. Added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you used the ID wrong.

JS:

```
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/x8dSP/3523/